# How to override spring security default filter?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want override a Spring-security default filter. What i really want to do is, spring-security checks if the user have authority to access index page if it's not then spring-security redirects page to login. I want to override this response. Is there anyway to do this?

**Edit:** Spring security filter returns ajax response so my page stucks and doesn't redirect to login page. What i want to do is override this filter.

My spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">



<http auto-config='false' use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/ajaxErrorPage" access="permitAll"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/pages/*" access="hasRole('admin')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="permitAll"/>        
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.xhtml" />
    <form-login login-page="/login.xhtml"
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"                                                       
                default-target-url="/pages/index.xhtml"
                always-use-default-target="true"                                                        
                authentication-failure-url="/login.xhtml"/>

</http>


<!--Authentication Manager Details -->    
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
        <!--            <password-encoder hash="md5"/>-->
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: share your spring security configuration and version used

Comment: Did I understand you right: you want to add some kind of spring security interceptor rule, that let all ajax requests pass (like `<intercept-header type="json" access ="permitAll">' (this is just for illustration, it does not exist to my knowledge))

Comment: @Ralph yes that kind.

Comment: You can write your own *AuthenticationEntryPoint* and *AccessDeniedHandler* with custom behavior.